# Can any space be seen as the boundary of some other space?

Tags: general-topology

For example two points can be seen as the boundary of a line segment in $\mathbb{R}$. The plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be seen as the boundary of some set in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and so on. Can any set be seen as the boundary of some other set?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/175800/which-sets-occur-as-boundaries-of-other-sets-in-topological-spaces

Comment: How can I delete this post since its already been answered?

Comment: you'd have to get me to delete my answer first

Comment: you get a badge if you delete with a score of 3 or more - 'disciplined' I think.